# Integration of Custom application(SP) and ADFS (Idp) and WSO2 IS

Tags: adfs3.0, wso2-identity-server

I need to integrate WSO2 IS (as Federation Idp) with ADFS (IdP). ADFS is talking with Active Directory. WSO2 and ADFS/AD are in different premises and service provider application will talk with WSO2 IS.

Kindly help in handshaking configuration between WSO2 IS and ADFS.

Answer (score 0):

This is just straight federation.

Import the WS02 metadata into ADFS as a CP and send the ADFS metadata to WS02 so they can import on their side.